# How to add a hover effect / highlight rows in a table in Google Data Studio?

Tags: highlight, looker-studio

I have found an example of a report and can't do this hover effect that highlights a column and a row in a table. How to do this?

My report is [here](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/reporting/1nqTse6OzEbgX4T1Otm7YClABYU4SnF0h/page/cs3J)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/0ca7295d-66f4-42d0-be0d-3d2c2b6b94c0) to demonstrate, as well as a GIF showing the process below:

**1) Chart**
***[Pivot Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7516660)***: with Heatmap

**2) Fields**
***Row Dimension***: `Day of Week`
***Column Dimension***: `Hour`

**3) Sort**
***Row #1***: `Day of Week` in *Ascending order*
***Column #1***: `Hour` in *Ascending order*

## GIF of creating a Pivot Table (with Heatmap):

[image: 3]]

## GIF of Highlight Colour feature in the Pivot Table (with Heatmap):

[image: 4]]